# Umbraco ExternalIndexer not indexing nodes

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

Has anyone seen this error before?

This is preventing the ExternalIndexer from indexing any nodes.

`2014-05-23 17:27:02,213 [7] ERROR UmbracoExamine.DataServices.UmbracoLogService - [Thread 11] Provider=ExternalIndexer, NodeId=-1
System.Exception: Error indexing queue items,The given key was not present in the dictionary., IndexSet: ExternalIndexSet`

Comment: Anyone know anything to fix it?